# c# Regex non letter characters from a string

Tags: c#, regex

My terminology may be a little out here, but i am trying to strip out non letters from a string in C#, so remove dashes ampersands etc, but retain things like accented characters and Chinese characters. All the C# examples i have seen on SO have a regex like this `new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]");`, but my needs are beyond ascii characters.

`string input = "I- +AM. 相关 AZURÉE& /30%";`

`string output = "I AM 相关 AZURÉE 30";`

Comment: How about stripping out characters where `char.IsLetterOrDigit` returns false? Something like `var sb = new StringBuilder(); foreach(var c in input) if(char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)) sb.Append(c); return sb.ToString();` - haven't tried it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good starting point would be to remove characters according to their [Unicode character class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories). For example, this code removes everything that is characterized as punctuation, symbol or a control character:

```
string input = "I- +AM. 相关 AZURÉE& /30%";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, "[\\p{S}\\p{C}\\p{P}]", "");
```

You could also try the whitelisting approach, by only allowing certain classes. For example, this keeps only characters that are letters, diacritics, digits and spacing:

```
var output = Regex.Replace(input, "[^\\p{L}\\p{M}\\p{N}\\p{Z}]", "");
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/snn0UI)**.

Comment: +1 For Ideone demonstration link. That site is pretty cool! Good find!

Answer (score 1):

```
string result = string.Concat(input.Where(c => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)));
```